# Unable to import or export classes or functions - React

Tags: reactjs

While learning React for the first time through a tutorial, I encounter this minor issue,
As I m aware that not to ask such simple questions in the stack, however I couldn't able to proceed further without fixing it.

Please note that I have wasted 3 hours browsing on similar questions and understanding from other answers.

The code Goes as :

**classcomp.js**

```
import React from 'react'

class classcomp extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <p>class classcomp extends React.Component</p>
    }
}

export default classcomp
```

**funccomp.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function funccomp() {
    return <p>Fucntional Comp</p>
}

export default funccomp
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import funccomp from "./comp/funccomp"
import classcomp from "./comp/classcomp"


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello01</h1>
      <funccomp />
      <classcomp />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the resulting output, all its prints are the Heading tag.

Comment: You spelled "function" wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Like this

Change funccomp to Funccomp and classcomp to Classcomp in App.js,funccomp.js and classcomp.js

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";

import Funccomp from "./comp/funccomp";
import Classcomp from "./comp/classcomp";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello01</h1>
      <Funccomp />
      <Classcomp />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**funccomp.js**

```
import React from "react";

function Funccomp() {
  return <p>Fucntional Comp</p>;
}

export default Funccomp;
```

**classcomp.js**

```
import React from "react";

class Classcomp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>class classcomp extends React.Component</p>;
  }
}

export default Classcomp;
```